# Which kernel version are stable/recommended for linux mint 18.2?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch

Distributor ID: LinuxMint

Description:    Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya

Release:    18.2

Codename:   sonya

Comment: Depends on issues you have noticed on your hardware or known security issues. You always can build kernel yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The version they have in their repo?
http://packages.linuxmint.com/search.php?release=any&section=any&keyword=kernel